# How to use ajax to post some content and then to retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

As you all can see that I'm a big NOOB to the javascript and jquery, but I have a question about ajax request.

Here is what I want to do but I don't know how:

- I declared a `content.append('<div id="box"><textarea>some content</textarea></div');`
- now I want to make that `text = $('textarea').value();` goes to ajax request.

something like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/localstorage/boxes",
    data: text,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

and then later I want to call that data back to another function `oldBox()` to show it back when user hits that event

**UPDATE**

```
function saveNote(){

        var theNote = $('div#note');
        var textValue = $this.$('textarea').value();
        var textData = JSON.stringify(textValue);


        $.ajax ({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/localstorage/notes",
            data: textData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                loadNote(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

This is good, it fixed my errors but when I try to locate localstorage/notes file its empty, should it be empty?

Comment: `$('textarea').val();` instead of `$('textarea').value();`

Comment: Thanks, I saw some people use .val() but I was not sure what to use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your examples worked, but I found the solution and here it is :)

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save", function(event) {
        var note = $(this).parent().parent().children("textarea").val();
        $.post( "main.php", { note: note });
    });
```

php:

```
<?
    $json = $_POST['note'];
    $form = json_decode( $json, true);

    print_r($form);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax, add this bit:

```
success: function(data) {
    oldBox(data);
}
```

So your ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/localstorage/boxes",
    data: text,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        oldBox(data);
    }
});
```

This is assuming your `oldBox()` function looks similar to this:

```
function oldBox(data) {
    $('.whatever').html(data);
}
```

But then you may as well just add this line (`$('.whatever').html(data);`) into the `success:`.

In `/localstorage/boxes` you need to echo out what you want for it to be retrieved by the ajax.

For example:

```
text = "Hello";
// text -> /localstorage/boxes
/localstorage/boxes echoes out 'Hi to you to!'
// /localstorage/boxes -> original page
oldBox('Hi to you to!');
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope to help, i think the problem is in your succes:

```
function saveNote(){

    var theNote = $('div#note');
    var textValue = $this.$('textarea').value();
    var textData = JSON.stringify(textValue);


    $.ajax ({
        method:'POST',
        url: '/localstorage/notes',
        type: 'POST',
        data: textData,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
        success: function(data) {
            loadNote(data);
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        loadNote(data);
    });

}
```

If this does not work

```
function saveNote(){

    var theNote = $('div#note');
    var textValue = $this.$('textarea').value();
    var textData = JSON.stringify(textValue);


    $.ajax ({
        method:'POST',
        url: '/localstorage/notes',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
        success: function(data) {
            loadNote(data);
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        loadNote(data);
    });

}
```

Comment: Both code works, but I have a problem, my local server on debian linux does not make a request to /localstorage/note

When I check the network in the inspect element view or in firebug it just makes GET requests to basic elements index.html jquery.js and main.js